# Angular 11 NgRx state management handling subscribe and unsubscribe in most effective way

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

Why I'm writing this question is to get more information and to gain more knowledge for state management and best practices.

I have been using NgRx as state management on my angular 11 project everything was fine at least I thought like that.

Generally how i implemented state management is in this file format:

[image]

where firstly I dispatch an **action** from there an **effect** that is connected with action that is being dispatched, inside effect I call the service and wait for a response if there is 200 status code I continue to a call another action where I send returned value from service and from that I call a **reducer** and after it, I return to state and with **selector** I access to data on store that I dispatched from the first action.

what is now confusing for me and that I think there is something wrong with my implementation is that, when I open a modal I call selector to listen for a change and with a function I call a action that is connected with an already called selector(I'm not sure if this part) this is the flow of code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getUserInformation$ = this.store
     .select(getUserInformation)
     .pipe()
     .subscribe((data) => {
        if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
           this.inviteUserForm.controls['name0'].setValue(data.test0);
           this.inviteUserForm.controls['name1'].setValue(data.test1);
           this.inviteUserForm.controls['name2'].setValue(data.test2);
           this.inviteUserForm.controls['name3'].setValue(data.test3);
           this.inviteUserForm.controls['name4'].setValue(data.test4);
           this.inviteUserForm.controls['name5'].setValue(data.test5);
        }
        if (data === null) {
           this.showQuestion();
        }
     });
}

setUserName() {
  this.store.dispatch(
     UserActions.verifyUser({
        id: this.inviteUserForm.controls.index.value,
     })
  );
}
```

what is confusing me is that when I close the modal I do the unsubscribe but when I open the modal the data that I had earlier is still there and that information is being subscribed from the store.

What I'm thinking to do is to call an action on **`ngOnDestroy()`** that changes the store so(i mean to delete the part of the store that I don't need to yous, in this case, a part the selector is listening and return it as a new state)

Is this the right decision and implementation?

Comment: Isn't the point of ngxs that you don't always send a webrequest when arriving on the modal? Each time the modal is destroyed by angular, and later a new modal is shown, you can pull the data from the state. The code you have now caches the requested data in javascript, so why would you remove it again?

Comment: I remove the data because whenever I open the modal it is supposed to be empty, but when I have data on store and in ngOnInit selector is listening for changes it emits values directly to modal

Comment: @Pieterjan is right, store just works like a cache. If you need to have empty modal each time, a new action to clear this data should be emitted each time after modal is closed.

Comment: I implemented that logic to dispatch an action to change store where I remove the unwanted object on the store so when the modal is open again it shows empty values who that is what I want.